# TLC passes property but the state is not existed

Tags: tla+

I'm a new user of TLA+. The following code might be silly. It's a narrowed-down version of my private code.
There are no lines assigning END to s on the following code but the Prop passes without error on TLC model check.

```
----------------------------- MODULE notExisted -----------------------------
EXTENDS Sequences
VARIABLES s, q

Init == /\ s = "S0"
        /\ q = <<>>

sub_nxt == /\ q' = Append(q, "wow")
           /\ UNCHANGED<<s>>

Next == \/ /\ s = "S0"
           /\ s' = "S1"
           /\ UNCHANGED<<q>>

Spec == /\ Init
        /\ [][Next]_<<s,q>>
        /\ SF_<<s,q>>(sub_nxt)

Prop == []<>(s = "END")

=============================================================================
```

I can't figure out why it passes. There might be bad pattern on my code.
Can anyone explain?
The TLA+ version is 1.7.1.
The OS is Ubuntu 20.04.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a self-answer.
I checked [Specifying Systems](https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/tla/book.html?back-link=tools.html#download) "14.3.5 Limitations of Liveness Checking" and finally figured out what was wrong. I think...
The SF is False since the Spec is finite and sub_nxt always true.
In that case, the `SF_<<s,q>>(sub_nxt) => []<>(s = "END")` is true.
The `A => B` is true when A is false.

I've also tried following and it also passes.

```
--------------------------- MODULE LimOfLivCheck ---------------------------
EXTENDS Integers
VARIABLE x

Spec == (x=0) /\ [][x' = x + 2 /\ x < 10]_x /\ WF_x(x' = x + 2)

Prop == []<>(x=1)

=============================================================================
```

Comment: Ah! Good job finding it, I was thinking it was that. I ran into the same thing a long time ago. Vacuous truth of material implication.

Comment: Thanks for vouching for me. Yeah, such behavior is dangerous. I want some warning message for that situation.

Comment: See this issue I filed a while back: https://github.com/tlaplus/tlaplus/issues/161